# Writing list to file

Tags: c, struct

I have a problem with writing list to file. Please check my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct record
{
   char name[30];
   int score;
} record;

int score = 23;
char winner[30] = "gracz";

typedef struct el_list
{
   record record;
   struct el_list* next;
} el_list;

el_list *first = NULL;

int addrecord()
{
   el_list *record;
   record = (el_list*) malloc (sizeof(el_list));
   record->next = NULL;
   record->record.score = score;
   strcpy(record->record.name, winner);
   return record;
}

void addtolist(el_list** first)
{
   el_list *pom, *tmp = addrecord();

   if (*first == NULL)
      *first = tmp;
   else if ((*first)->record.score > tmp->record.score)
   {
      tmp->next = *first;
      *first = tmp;
   }
   else
   {
      pom = (*first);
      while((pom->next != NULL) && (pom->record.score < tmp->record.score))
         pom = pom->next;
      tmp->next = pom->next;
      pom->next = tmp;
   }
}

void save2file(el_list* first)
{
   el_list *tmp;
   FILE *hs = fopen("highscores.txt", "w");
   if( hs == NULL)
      perror("Blad z plikiem.");
   else
   {
      tmp = first;
      while(tmp != NULL)
      {
         fprintf( hs, "%d %s\n", score, winner);
         tmp = tmp->next;
      }
   }
   fclose(hs);
}

int main()
{
   addtolist(&first);
   save2file(&first);
   return 0;
}
```

Probably I have problem with while in save2file.

Sorry for my English. ;)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. Please post the relevant code here itself.

Comment: Change call `save2file(&first);` to `save2file(first);` , not no `&` .

Comment: also, move `fclose(hs);` inside the `else` block.

Comment: even after the kind addition by Mr. @unwind , its not clear. Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're saving `score` and `winner`, which are global variables unrelated to the current list item in `tmp`.

Also, for clarity's sake, you should open the output file in text mode, i.e. with `fopen("highscores.txt", "wt")`.